# Request.Cookie - Cookie is not sent or not excepted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a shopping cart function.
I need product data from the server that used to render the shopping cart page.

Every time the Add-to-cart button is hit, I stringify this array ( using JSON.stringify() ):

```
  var CART = [{productId: 102, quantity: 3} , {productId: 211, quantity: 6}];
```

I want to get this data using `Request.Cookie["shoppingCart"]` in my ASP.NET application,
but when I debug It is always `null`

This is what the browser return when I call `document.cookie`

```
"shoppingCart=[{\"productId\":101617121,\"quantity\":2}]"
```

[image]

But when I try to change the value of the cookie to something like: `shoppingCart=testresult` ,
the `Request.Cookie["shoppingCart"]` then has value.

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
First, I tried to remove some special chars which are:  `"` and `,` .

And `Request.Cookie` then had values. So it seems like ASP.NET just doesn't except these characters in cookie value. ( Tell me if I'm wrong please )

My solution was instead of convert JSON string, I used this formular for each product in the shopping cart : `` var item = `{productId}:{quantity}`; `` .

For example:

```
var sampleCookie = "11231:16:15121:8";
```

Split the string with `:` char then use a simple code to get the data.

My code for this:

```
            string cookie = Request.Cookies["shoppingCart"];

            var cartItems = new List<CartItem>();
            if (cookie != null && cookie.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] values;
                values = cookie.Split(':');

                int i = 0;
                while (i < values.Length)
                {
                    cartItems.Add(new CartItem()
                    {
                        ProductId = values[i],
                        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(values[i+1])
                    });

                    i += 2;
                }
            }
```